# jQuery Waypoints and menu items

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am having problems highlighting the right menu item when using Waypoints on my website (or triggering the waypoints at all, I can't tell). The second section of my content (#work) works just fine but the first and third one do not (#about and #contact). My jquery skills are not good so I need some help please!

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="about">..</section>
<section id="work">...</section>
<section id="contact">...</section>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#about').waypoint(function() {
    $('.nav .active').removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li:nth-child(1)').addClass("active");
})
$('#work').waypoint(function() {
    $('.nav .active').removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li:nth-child(2)').addClass("active");
})
$('#contact').waypoint(function() {
    $('.nav .active').removeClass("active");
    $('.nav li:nth-child(3)').addClass("active");
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting up a working example at http://jsfiddle.net